# Cuando doy en mi evento onclick mandando una fecha me resta

Tags: javascript, mysql, bootstrap, onclick

Sucede que estoy desarrollando un sistema en php y el resultado de una consulta es esto:

```
<?php
$data = '<table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Conductor</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>';



//if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
   // exit(mysql_error());
//}

// if query results contains rows then featch those rows 
if(isset($_POST['i_conductor']))
{
    $i_conductor = $_POST['i_conductor'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT c.id_conductor,c.nombre_conductor,c.apellido_conductor,SUM(s.precio) AS precio,s.fecha_servicio FROM servicios s INNER JOIN conductor c ON s.id_conductor = c.id_conductor WHERE c.id_conductor = $i_conductor GROUP BY s.fecha_servicio"); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $id_conductor = $row["id_conductor"];
        $conductor = $row["nombre_conductor"]. " " .$row["apellido_conductor"];
        $precio = $row["precio"];
        $fecha = $row["fecha_servicio"];
        $fecha_format = strtotime($fecha);
        $fecha_format2 = date('d-m-Y',$fecha_format);

        $data .= '<tr>
            <td id="detalle_conductor" name="detalle_conductor" value='.$id_conductor.'>'.$id_conductor.'</td>
            <td>'.$conductor.'</td>
            <td>'.$precio.'</td>
            <td id="detalle_conductor_fecha" name="detalle_conductor_fecha" value='.$fecha.'>'.$fecha_format2.'</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" id="fecha_servicio" name="fecha_servicio" value='.$fecha.' onclick="DetalleIngresos('.$id_conductor.','.$fecha.')"  class="btn btn-borders btn-primary mr-xs mb-sm">Ver Detalles</button>
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    // records now found 
    $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No existe ningun dato!</td></tr>';
}

$data .= '</table>';

echo $data;
```

Sin embargo, como se pueden dar cuenta, hay un `onclick()` con dos parámetros, uno es un id, y el otro es una fecha, sucede que cuando carga la página todo bien, incluso si le doy `F12` para ver si paso la variable veo que en el `onclick` dice DetalleIngresos(2,2017-12-15) pero cuando le hago `click`,esa fecha me lo transforma en 1990, es decir esos "-" lo toma como si fueran resta. Entonces como hago, por que esa fecha la necesito para que al hace `click` me lleve a otra consulta que la paso por `AJAX` a un `PHP` donde la fecha es un parámetro importante 
y es como si en el where dijera 1990 pero necesito 2017-12-15.

Aquí mi código `JAVASCRIPT` de DetalleIngresos()  :

```
function DetalleIngresos(d_id_conductor,d_fecha) {
d_fecha_ingresos = d_fecha;
$("#hidden_user_id").val(d_id_conductor);
$("#hidden_user_fecha").val(d_fecha_ingresos);
$.post("ajax/reportes/detalle_ingresos_conductor.php", {
        detalle_conductor : d_id_conductor,
        detalle_conductor_fecha : d_fecha,
    },
    function (data, status) {
        $(".mostrar_detalle_ingresos_por_conductor").html(data);
    }
);
// Open modal popup
$("#detalle_ingresos_modal").modal("show");
}
```

Y esta es la consulta que hace en `PHP`  :

```
<?php
// include Database connection file 
    include("abrir_conexion.php");

    $data = '<table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID Servicio</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                    </tr>';

if(isset($_POST['detalle_conductor']) && isset($_POST['detalle_conductor_fecha']))
{
    $detalle_conductor = $_POST['detalle_conductor'];
    $d_fecha_ingresos = $_POST['detalle_conductor_fecha'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT s.id_servicio,s.precio,s.fecha_servicio FROM servicios s INNER JOIN conductor c ON s.id_conductor = c.id_conductor WHERE c.id_conductor = $detalle_conductor AND s.fecha_servicio = '$d_fecha_ingresos' "); 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $id_servicio = $row["id_servicio"];
        $precio = $row["precio"];
        $fecha = $row["fecha_servicio"];
        $fecha_format = strtotime($fecha);
        $fecha_format2 = date('d-m-Y',$fecha_format);

        $data .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$id_servicio.'</td>
            <td>'.$precio.'</td>
            <td>'.$fecha_format2.'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    // records now found 
    $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No existe ningun dato!</td></tr>';
}

$data .= '</table>';

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Buenos días, te recomiendo que leas la sección [ask], y que coloques el código que tienes para la función `DetalleIngresos`

Comment: ¿Que es lo urgente? =)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a encerrar la fecha entre comillas, tal como la pasas nunca funcionará. El resultado debería ser algo como lo siguiente:

DetalleIngresos(2, '2017-12-15')

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero prueba a cambiar el button a esta manera y me comentas si se ha solucionado tu problema:

```
<button type="button" id="fecha_servicio" name="fecha_servicio" value='.$fecha.' onclick="DetalleIngresos('.$id_conductor.',\"'.$fecha.'\")"  class="btn btn-borders btn-primary mr-xs mb-sm">Ver Detalles</button>
```

O sino:

```
<button type="button" id="fecha_servicio" name="fecha_servicio" value='.$fecha.' onclick="DetalleIngresos('.$id_conductor.',\''.$fecha.'\')"  class="btn btn-borders btn-primary mr-xs mb-sm">Ver Detalles</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda :')

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría hacer un par de cambios.

En tu `PHP`, a la hora de crear el botón, para el paso de parámetros, encierra entre comillas la fecha

```
<button type="button" id="fecha_servicio" name="fecha_servicio" value='.$fecha.' onclick="DetalleIngresos('.$id_conductor.',\''.$fecha.'\')"  class="btn btn-borders btn-primary mr-xs mb-sm">Ver Detalles</button>
```

En tu `JavaScript`, prueba a definirte la variable de tipo fecha

```
var d_fecha_ingresos = new Date('d_fecha');
```

Comment: Eres un genio hermano, Gracias por tu ayuda.